# Three queries mysql in one object json

Tags: php, mysql, json, slim

I want JSON output to be like this and it's getting this from 3 different queries I am running in SQL and saving to 3 different arrays

```
    {
      "category_level2":[
     {
        "name":"First",
        "img":"60",
     },
     {
       "name":"First",
        "img":"60",
     }],
  "products":[
     {
        "title":"First",
        "sku":"60"
     },
     {
        "title":"First",
        "sku":"60"
     }
  ],
  "category_level1":[
     {
        "name":"First",
        "img":"60"
     },
     {
        "name":"First",
        "img":"60"
     }]
  }
```

I am saving the result of all the queries in different arrays ...
How to encode them in one JSON

```
    $query = $db->rawQuery("SELECT * FROM `category_level2` WHERE `name` LIKE  '%{$res->query}%'");
    if ($query)
        {
        foreach($query as $query)
            {
            array_push($category_level2, array(
                'name' => $query["name"],
                'img' => $query["img"]
            ));
            }
        }

    $query = $db->rawQuery("SELECT * FROM `stocklots` WHERE `title` LIKE  '%{$res->query}%'");
   if ($query)
        {
        foreach($query as $query)
            {
            array_push($result, array(
                'title' => $query["title"],
                'sku' => $query["sku"]
            ));}}
```

Comment: Can you please show all three `SELECT` queries and the associated code?

Comment: First, you can combine all three queries into one using JOINS or other combinations of tables or you can merge the 3 arrays into one before encoding into JSON like below;

Comment: $query3 = $db->rawQuery("SELECT * FROM `category_level1` WHERE `name` LIKE  '%{$res->query}%'");
        if ($query2)
            {
            foreach($query2 as $query2)
                {
                array_push($category_level1, array(
                    'name' => $query["name"],
                    'img' => $query["img"]
                ));
                }
            }

Answer (score 0):

First, you can combine all three queries into one using JOINS or other combinations of tables or you can merge the 3 arrays into one before encoding into JSON like below;

```
echo $finalArray = json_encode (array_merge($ar1, $arr2, $arr3));
```

[More on Array Merge and Append](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys but I figured out myself .This will work

```
    $json=json_encode(array('category_level2' => $category_level2, 'products' => $result, 'category_level1' => $category_level1));

echo json_encode($json);
```

I am getting my desired output

```
{"category_level2":[{"name":"Leather Furniture","img":"https:\/\/mobilees4332.blob.core.windows.net\/bulkiy-stocklots\/category-level-1-1670.jpg","id":1670,"level_1_id":"1628"},{"name":"Finished Leather","img":"https:\/\/mobilees4332.blob.core.windows.net\/bulkiy-stocklots\/category-level-1-1118.jpg","id":1118,"level_1_id":"2413"},{"name":"Leather Accessories","img":"https:\/\/mobilees4332.blob.core.windows.net\/bulkiy-stocklots\/category-level-1-2415.jpg","id":2415,"level_1_id":"2413"},{"name":"Leather Bags","img":"https:\/\/mobilees4332.blob.core.windows.net\/bulkiy-stocklots\/category-level-1-945.jpg","id":945,"level_1_id":"2413"},{"name":"Leather Belts","img":"https:\/\/mobilees4332.blob.core.windows.net\/bulkiy-stocklots\/category-level-1-2416.jpg","id":2416,"level_1_id":"2413"},{"name":"Leather Boots","img":"https:\/\/mobilees4332.blob.core.windows.net\/bulkiy-stocklots\/category-level-1-2417.jpg","id":2417,"level_1_id":"2413"},{"name":"Leather Cases","img":"https:\/\/mobilees4332.blob.core.windows.net\/bulkiy-stocklots\/category-level-1-2418.jpg","id":2418,"level_1_id":"2413"},{"name":"Leather Chemicals","img":"https:\/\/mobilees4332.blob.core.windows.net\/bulkiy-stocklots\/category-level-1-840.jpg","id":840,"level_1_id":"2413"},{"name":"Leather Clothing","img":"https:\/\/mobilees4332.blob.core.windows.net\/bulkiy-stocklots\/category-level-1-2419.jpg","id":2419,"level_1_id":"2413"},{"name":"Leather Finishing Transfer Foils","img":"https:\/\/mobilees4332.blob.core.windows.net\/bulkiy-stocklots\/category-level-1-1388.jpg","id":1388,"level_1_id":"2413"},{"name":"Leather Garment","img":"https:\/\/mobilees4332.blob.core.windows.net\/bulkiy-stocklots\/category-level-1-43.jpg","id":43,"level_1_id":"2413"},{"name":"Leather Gloves","img":"https:\/\/mobilees4332.blob.core.windows.net\/bulkiy-stocklots\/category-level-1-2420.jpg","id":2420,"level_1_id":"2413"},{"name":"Leather Jackets","img":"https:\/\/mobilees4332.blob.core.windows.net\/bulkiy-stocklots\/category-level-1-2421.jpg","id":2421,"level_1_id":"2413"},{"name":"Leather Pouches","img":"https:\/\/mobilees4332.blob.core.windows.net\/bulkiy-stocklots\/category-level-1-2422.jpg","id":2422,"level_1_id":"2413"},{"name":"Leather Products","img":"https:\/\/mobilees4332.blob.core.windows.net\/bulkiy-stocklots\/category-level-1-690.jpg","id":690,"level_1_id":"2413"},{"name":"Leather Purses","img":"https:\/\/mobilees4332.blob.core.windows.net\/bulkiy-stocklots\/category-level-1-2423.jpg","id":2423,"level_1_id":"2413"},{"name":"Leather Raw Materials","img":"https:\/\/mobilees4332.blob.core.windows.net\/bulkiy-stocklots\/category-level-1-700.jpg","id":700,"level_1_id":"2413"},{"name":"Leather Saddles","img":"https:\/\/mobilees4332.blob.core.windows.net\/bulkiy-stocklots\/category-level-1-1830.jpg","id":1830,"level_1_id":"2413"},{"name":"Leather Sandals","img":"https:\/\/mobilees4332.blob.core.windows.net\/bulkiy-stocklots\/category-level-1-2424.jpg","id":2424,"level_1_id":"2413"},{"name":"Leather Shoes","img":"https:\/\/mobilees4332.blob.core.windows.net\/bulkiy-stocklots\/category-level-1-2425.jpg","id":2425,"level_1_id":"2413"},{"name":"Leather Strings","img":"https:\/\/mobilees4332.blob.core.windows.net\/bulkiy-stocklots\/category-level-1-1309.jpg","id":1309,"level_1_id":"2413"},{"name":"Leather Wallets","img":"https:\/\/mobilees4332.blob.core.windows.net\/bulkiy-stocklots\/category-level-1-2426.jpg","id":2426,"level_1_id":"2413"},{"name":"PVC Leather Cloth","img":"https:\/\/mobilees4332.blob.core.windows.net\/bulkiy-stocklots\/category-level-1-1124.jpg","id":1124,"level_1_id":"2413"},{"name":"Synthetic Leather","img":"https:\/\/mobilees4332.blob.core.windows.net\/bulkiy-stocklots\/category-level-1-1274.jpg","id":1274,"level_1_id":"2413"},{"name":"Leather Machinery","img":"https:\/\/mobilees4332.blob.core.windows.net\/bulkiy-stocklots\/category-level-1-1123.jpg","id":1123,"level_1_id":"1215"}],"products":[{"title":"Leather Notecase Wallet","sku":"XS-STK-27724","image":"https:\/\/gabproject.org\/images\/sho
```